# How to properly outline an Apache Solr document?

Tags: java, apache, solr

1. What is the difference between `delta import` and `full import` in `ApacheSolr`?
2. What are all the naming conventions to be followed while writing `deltaImportQuery` and `deltaQuery` ( `ID`, `TXT_ID` etc), any references or tutorial explaining in detail about differences/relations between `deltaImportQuery` and `deltaQuery`, Like what it is and what it does etc, How to write `deltaImportQuery` and `deltaQuery` ?
3. How to configure `multiple entities` in `one document`, Suppose if there are three tables in database like T1, T2, T3, Then in schema.xml how to configure this, issue with only one `<uniquekey>somename</uniquekey>` been considered for each `schema.xml` file?
4. How to parse `BLOB` type input from `mysql`, following `convert ( column_name using utf8 ) as alias_name` solves this but what is the right convention ,some other methods are also available like using  `TikaEntityProcessor`/  writing custom `BLOBTRANSFORMERS`  etc ?
5. Just like `ORM` any concepts explaining how to `denormalize` and `outline` an `Apache Solr` `document` , Any showcase project including all use cases and features ?

How to configure `entities` like this in `data-config.xml`?

```
 <dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/solrdemo" user="root" password="123" batchSize='1' />
    <document name="user">
        <entity name ="user1" query = "SELECT * FROM user1">
            <field column='id' name='id1' />
        </entity>
        <entity name ="user2" query = "SELECT * FROM user2">
            <field column='id' name='id2' />
        </entity>

        <entity name ="user3" query = "SELECT * FROM user3">
            <field column='id' name='id3' />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

When the above kind of configuration is done then in `schema.xml` which `id` should be configured into `<uniquekey></uniquekey>` ?

The result of above configuration is

```
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 2,866 documents. Deleted 0 documents. (Duration: 03s)
```

Indexing is successfully completed but 0 documents added / updated , How to resolve this issue ?

Overall any references available for proper conventions and configurations to work with `Apache Solr`?